# View background color can not work with selector?

Tags: android, listview, selector

I am working on an android application , and I have a lot of items to display by the `ListView`:

```
    <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/bg_selector"/>
```

bg_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="#8F136fb8"/>
</selector>
```

And I want each item have a different background color, and I set them in the `getView` method of the `adapter`:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        .....
        Color color=generateColor();
        viewHolder.textView.setBackgroundColor(color);
        return convertView;
    }
```

However I found that that once I select an item, there is no effect responded to the user event I set the `selector` to the `ListView`[image]

Answer (score 1):

**problem:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="#8F136fb8"/>
</selector>
```

you need to have a default color when the item is not clicked or else it wont work

**sample:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="#8F136fb8"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: I can not set the default color, since this color is calculated at runtime. As shown in my scrrenshot(left) in my post, the default color is different.

Comment: @hguser Is the problem the selector is not working am I right?

Comment: I am not sure but I wonder if the backgroundcolor can be work together with the selector.

Comment: @hguser you can assign the selector to each of the item of the listview  to have a selector effect

Comment: `viewHolder.textView.setBackgroundColor(color);   viewHolder.textView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_selector));` While this add the selector, but the background color is removed.

Comment: @hguser put the textview in a parent layout lets say relative layout with with another view, textView is for the background and the other view is for selector